# Redundant periodic task execution

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, amazon-web-services

My server system will have the need to run a set of tasks once a minute. It is very important that these tasks gets executed (some minor delay is ok, but not executed twice) so I need to build the execution system in a redundant way that would survive even if a single server stops responding. I have been searching for some best practices on this from an architecture/system components point of view but don't seem to find anything suitable.

Problem simplified.

Send notification emails for meetings about to start for all my users that have a calender with booked meetings in my system. - Meetings can start at any given minute. - The notification should always come 10 minutes before the meeting - Same notification should not be sent twice - Servers stops responding (or needs to be replaced or updated).

I have been investigating Amazon Webservices Simple Workflow Management but it seems more suitable for tasks that have a defined start and end.

My system currently runs in Amazon Web Services, .NET and C#.

Any one out there that have any suggestions?

Thanks David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use aws SQS and put into the queue one message for each email notification that needs to be sent.

You can have as many worker processes (servers) requesting 'work' from the queue, downloading a message at a time(or more than one at a time if you want), and then if the process completes successfully the worker process would remove the message from the queue.

If a server dies after requesting a message, but before the email is sent, SQS will automatically make that item available in the queue for another worker/server to process after the allotted timeout.

Depending on how many messages you may need to process, and if you are liable to see occasional spikes in the work to be done,  you can also use the size of the SQS queue as a metric to kick off additional ec2 servers to help handle the spike in traffic and  service the queue - then you can can automatically remove servers as the spike in messages to be processed goes down to a pre-defined level.

As far as the processing at a one-minute interval, you could either use a windows service, or a simple scheduled task than is set to run every 60 seconds (my personal preference).

Comment: Thanks for your insights. What about the redundancy of putting new items in the queue. As I understand it there is no way to check if a certain item is in the queue and if the process that adds items to the queue halts I am in a state that I cant recover from (should anything be added or not). Also changes to meeting times is hard to propagate out in the SQS system.